# Pandas profiling installation issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install pandas profiling for my python 3.9 but I am getting following error

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\deepankar.srigyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\deepankar.srigyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-umhjf2qg'
       cwd: C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\
  Complete output (24 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  c:\program files\python39\python.exe C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\ffi\build.py
  Trying generator 'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\ffi\build.py", line 191, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\ffi\build.py", line 179, in main
      main_win32()
    File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\ffi\build.py", line 88, in main_win32
      generator = find_win32_generator()
    File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\ffi\build.py", line 76, in find_win32_generator
      try_cmake(cmake_dir, build_dir, generator)
    File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\ffi\build.py", line 28, in try_cmake
      subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '-G', generator, cmake_dir])
    File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 368, in check_call
      retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 349, in call
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
    File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
      self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
      hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  error: command 'c:\\program files\\python39\\python.exe' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite
  Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Successfully built htmlmin phik numba
Failed to build llvmlite
Installing collected packages: llvmlite, visions, seaborn, pyyaml, numba, joblib, imagehash, phik, missingno, htmlmin, confuse, pandas-profiling
    Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\deepankar.srigyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\deepankar.srigyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b8w87a9s\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\llvmlite'
         cwd: C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\
    Complete output (27 lines):
    running install
    running build
    got version from file C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.34.0', 'full': 'c5889c9e98c6b19d5d85ebdd982d64a03931f8e2'}
    running build_ext
    c:\program files\python39\python.exe C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\ffi\build.py
    Trying generator 'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\ffi\build.py", line 191, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\ffi\build.py", line 179, in main
        main_win32()
      File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\ffi\build.py", line 88, in main_win32
        generator = find_win32_generator()
      File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\ffi\build.py", line 76, in find_win32_generator
      File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\ffi\build.py", line 28, in try_cmake
        subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '-G', generator, cmake_dir])
      File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 368, in check_call
        retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
      File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 349, in call
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
      File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    error: command 'c:\\program files\\python39\\python.exe' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\deepankar.srigyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\deepankar.srigyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f8wf7qrw\\llvmlite_c4d61e4b18df4bdcac3bf703b9b2fa02\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b8w87a9s\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\llvmlite' Check the logs for full command output.

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\deepankar.srigyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z73__4g4\\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\deepankar.srigyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z73__4g4\\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-9clvl4qc'
       cwd: C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\
  Complete output (24 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  c:\program files\python39\python.exe C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\ffi\build.py
  Trying generator 'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\ffi\build.py", line 191, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\ffi\build.py", line 179, in main
      main_win32()
    File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\ffi\build.py", line 88, in main_win32
      generator = find_win32_generator()
    File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\ffi\build.py", line 76, in find_win32_generator
      try_cmake(cmake_dir, build_dir, generator)
    File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\ffi\build.py", line 28, in try_cmake
      subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '-G', generator, cmake_dir])
    File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 368, in check_call
      retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 349, in call
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
    File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
      self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
      hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  error: command 'c:\\program files\\python39\\python.exe' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite
  Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Failed to build llvmlite
Installing collected packages: llvmlite, visions, seaborn, pyyaml, numba, joblib, imagehash, phik, missingno, htmlmin, confuse, pandas-profiling
    Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\deepankar.srigyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z73__4g4\\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\deepankar.srigyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z73__4g4\\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bs31y1_3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\llvmlite'
         cwd: C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\
    Complete output (27 lines):
    running install
    running build
    got version from file C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.34.0', 'full': 'c5889c9e98c6b19d5d85ebdd982d64a03931f8e2'}
    running build_ext
    c:\program files\python39\python.exe C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\ffi\build.py
    Trying generator 'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\ffi\build.py", line 191, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\ffi\build.py", line 179, in main
        main_win32()
      File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\ffi\build.py", line 88, in main_win32
        generator = find_win32_generator()
      File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\ffi\build.py", line 76, in find_win32_generator
      File "C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z73__4g4\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\ffi\build.py", line 28, in try_cmake
        subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '-G', generator, cmake_dir])
      File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 368, in check_call
        retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
      File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 349, in call
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
      File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "c:\program files\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    error: command 'c:\\program files\\python39\\python.exe' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\deepankar.srigyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z73__4g4\\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\deepankar.srigyan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z73__4g4\\llvmlite_76d7f7d47906493c846af53e5a63eb5c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bs31y1_3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\deepankar.srigyan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\llvmlite' Check the logs for full command output.
```

how can I install it.

Comment: hey, did you solve it? just checking up.

Comment: I degrade my pip and i was able to install it.

Answer (score 0):

me degrade my pip and me was able to install it.